Ola Hallengren Maintenance Solution Upgrade
I’m relatively new to SQL Server and my company is currently using an older version (2014) of the Ola Hallengren Maintenance Solution. We’re looking to upgrade to a version that supports SQL Server 2022.
Has anyone here had experience with this type of upgrade? Are there specific considerations or potential issues to watch out for during the upgrade process? Or can we just replace the old version with the new one and then create new jobs etc?
Any advice or insights would really help, thankyou!

The newest available version certainly works with SQL Server 2022. You can install it in a different database than your current version (it can be tempdb or a dedicated database that you'll create for tests) and try it before replacing the old one (that's presumably in the master database).
